# Angular renew directive after scope variable change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just started with angular and I ran into a little issue.
In my for example SirroccoListing template I have the following stuff, Sirrocco is a directive:

```
<h3>All Sirroccos</h3>

<div sirrocco ng-repeat="sirrocco in sirroccos" 
     idx="{{ $index }}"></div>
<div sirrocco ng-model="sirroccoListing.addSirrocco" 
     idx="{{ sirroccos.length }}" 
     add-button="true" 
     class="add-sirrocco"></div>
```

Basically, what I want is to display all the [sirroccos] and add another sirrocco which is a slight different sirrocco (sort of add-button).

The [sirroccos] (scope array) are loaded via REST call and can be updated, that works fine.
The problem is, I want the add-button sirrocco to be rendered after the [sirroccos], because the idx attribute is important. How? So it also needs to be re-rendered after [sirroccos](amount of) change.

I hope my point is clear and you guys can help me.

Have a nice day!

Comment: well .. you could have used a better name thank thingies :). try using ng-if='thingies.length' on the button

Comment: Fair enough, edited my question ;-)
The ng-if won't work, because I always want an add-sirrocco directive, independent of there are any sirroccos or not.

Comment: Then when loading the sirroccos add a variable in the controller set to true when loading and false when done ... Hide button when variable is true

Answer (score 1):

> idx="{{ sirroccos.length }}"

You are using one way binding '@' for idx, and, **giving it by value**  you have to use two-way binding using '=' in the sirrocco directive and remove {{ }}, so, it should be :

```
> idx="sirroccos.length"
```

This, will allow you using a two-way binding and having the update of .length each time.